# set font-size on <div> children

Tags: css

```
<div class="pluginTitle"><h2>Latest Posts</h2></div>
```

How can I set `font-size:11px` of `<h2>` elements that are children of `.pluginTitle` class with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the child selector [`>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) to select children

```css
.pluginTitle > h2 { font-size:11px }
```

Comment: @michele sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.pluginTitle h2 { font-size: 11px; }
```